# "No property ... found for type List!"

Tags: scala, spring-data-mongodb

An entity class:

```
class Person{

  @BeanProperty
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Id
  var id: String = _

  @BeanProperty
  var firstName: String = _

  @BeanProperty
  var lastName: String = _
}
```

and its MongoDB repository Scala trait(the counterpart of Java interface in Scala):

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
trait PersonRepository extends MongoRepository[Person, String]{

  def findByLastName(@Param("name") name: String): List[Person]
}
```

And I get an exception for the return data type:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property lastName found for type List!
```

If I don't specific the return type, nothing will get returned with the method.

Based on my online search, it seems to be a known problem. I haven't seen a solution though. I guess that the proper field needs to be mapped to a return somehow. If so, how to do a such mapping?

Comment: This might be because you are using a Scala `List` and JPA doesn't know what to do with that. Try using a `java.util.List` instead: `def findByLastName(...): java.util.List[Person]`

Comment: You are absolutely right. After replacing the list type with Java one, the method works.